# Iveco VIN Database (Decode)

Tags: registration

I can't decode vehicle VIN numbers:

```
ZCFA1AD1202576571
ZCFA1AD1202576573
```

I tried almost all databases what could I find, but no success. 
I need to find the vehicle registration date.

Does anybody know another way how to find it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to determine the assembly date or the date of first sale?

Comment: i'm trying to determine assembly date.

Answer (score 1):

You can't find the vehicle registration date from the VIN, as the VIN is a manufacturer's number. You'll need to apply to the relevant registration authority for the country/state the vehicles are registered in.

Answer (score 1):

It is typically on the sticker on the drivers side door or on a sticker on the door jamb. If it is missing the dealer can determine it by the VIN

Answer (score 1):

Both VIN numbers relate to 2005 vehicles.

If you bear in mind that FIAT group manufacture Iveco vehicles (although in the UK at least they are sold through the Ford dealer network), you can simply apply a FIAT VIN decode.

The one I used specifically was [here](http://www.vindecoderz.com/EN/Fiat).