# Is this Vehicle id number VIN incorrect/flawed ZFA225000-0-0138627?

Tags: fiat, vin

According to what I have read about the [vehicle identification number encoding (model year)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_identification_number#Model_year_encoding)

> One consistent element of the VIS is the 10th digit, which is required
>   worldwide to encode the model year of the vehicle. Besides the three
>   letters that are not allowed in the VIN itself (I, O and Q), the
>   letters U and Z and the digit 0 are not used for the model year code.
>   The year code is the model year for the vehicle.

However in the documents about a *Fiat Qubo* vehicle I read this VIN: `ZFA225000-0-0138627`

It appears to me that it contradicts the rule, as its 10th digit is a either `0`(zero) or `O`(letter oh), of which both should not appear here, (i.e. I read the VIN visually and hence the uncertainty about the `0`/`O` situation, which either way should be "*wrong*", right?)

Not only wikipedia, but also this source https://researchmaniacs.com/VIN/VIN-Decoder.html mentions `0`/`O` being not correct in that location.

Background: The `VIN` is from an Italian car, from an Italian manufacturer, offered to me in Italy, from an Italian person.

Hence I imagine:

1. Wikipedia and the other source being inaccurate (i.e.  `0` may appear in the **10th** position of the VIN), or
2. Fiat made a mistake
3. The documents are maybe counterfeit?

Comment: You should check with Fiat (easy as you seem to be in Italy) and with the Police and/or the vehicle licensing / registration authorities.

Comment: FWIW the given VIN checks out as a Fiat Qubo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Wikipedia link you gave says clearly that

- There are (at least four) different standards for the VIN.
- The EU and North America use different standards.
- The European standard does *not* have explicit "model year" and "plant code" fields. Characters 10-17 simply provide "clear identification of a particular vehicle".

FWIW my Fiat (bought new from a reputable UK dealer) also has a zero in position 10 of the VIN.

Since in the UK (at least) the VIN is included on national databases (e.g. vehicle registration and annual safety checks) it is highly unlikely that "Fiat made a mistake" either globally, or on one individual car (or two individual cars, if you claim my VIN is also wrong!)

Comment: When I was at one of the "large" car manufacturers - we would de-code the VIN into groups of 3 letters and could completely decipher the original build specification of the vehicle - which radio, speakers, seats, trim, color of carpets, paint & finish etc

Comment: @SolarMike Manufacturers can use the VDS part of the VIN (which shows "the general characteristics of the vehicle") any way they like. Presumably that is what you were decoding. The question is not about that field. Apart from the Manufacturer code (ZFA=Fiat) all the rest of my VIN is numeric.

Comment: yes, we were taking the numeric part to decode.... It was a comment and from the vin we could tell which plant produced a specific vehicle... Which caused some embarrassment once to management...

Comment: @SolarMike, in my version of English "letters" are not "numeric." But whatever.....

Comment: We used **all** the letters and numerals for the decoding... It tells the whole story... In fact there are some websites now that do that for general users...

Comment: Another [question related to IVECO (which is part of fiat, right)](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/6515/46896) also features a `0` within the 10th place. It seems hence to be common. The Europeans seem to not use the VIN checksum either, so neither **model year**, nor **checksum** in European VIM, but hey (we got ourselves into censorship-online-filters too, it might be that EU is not so smart ;)

Comment: Maybe reason the USA motor industry invented "model years" at all was to persuade people to buy new cars when the only change from the old car was a different model year ;) In any case, checksums are pointless unless you have 19th-century record-keeping systems that rely on people copying numbers on bits of paper. But the USA is never going to get two states to do anything the same way, let alone set up *national* vehicle registration and insurance databases :)

Comment: @humanityANDpeace IVECO was originally formed as a merger of Fiat's "Industrial division" (translation of the original Italian name) and four other companies, two Italian, one French and one German. Eventually, IVECO and two other companies merged to form a new company called "Fiat Industrial" (not a translation!). Sometimes real life gets confusing...